# Probability of termination of random teleportation

Tags: recreational-mathematics, infinity, random-walk

In Minecraft, with mods, there's a liquid called Resonant Ender, which if you touch it, teleports you randomly up to 8 blocks on both the north-south and east-west axes.

Consider an infinite sea of Resonant Ender, with a single island of finite area in it. If you touch the sea, what is the probability of you ever making it back to dry land? What's the probability of making it in under time $t$?

I suspect this is close enough to a simple two-dimensional random walk, meaning it is Almost Certain that you will eventually land on any given block. I'm not certain, though - does the teleportation change things meaningfully?

Comment: You are right, this is very close to a 2d random walk. So yes, it will almost surely visit any place you want, in particular, the island. The exact probability to reach it in $t$ or less steps is not a very pleasant thing, but the complementary probability is of the same order as for simple 2d random walk.

Comment: My gut says that if you treat each $8\times8$ square as a single space, it reduces to a random walk with diagonals allowed, and a slight bias towards not moving on any given step. That would mean that you will almost surely visit any given $8\times8$ chunk, so if the island is at least $8\times8$ you're ok. I think a separate proof would be needed to demonstrate that you will almost surely visit any single square, though.